# Remove rows that net each other out

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a result set that contains; order_ids, a total for that order, and the quantities of items within.

Some totals are negative (if a refund has occurred) and others are positive. I would like to work out a count of the orders who's order_total, doesn't net out with with the negative values.

```
orders_id  order_total    products_quantity  customers_id  
---------  -------------  -----------------  --------------
  1140898  -99.95830000   -1                         459800
  1140868  99.95830000    1                          459800
  1140867  99.95833333    1                          459800
   866932  -106.33333333  -2                         459800
   860100  125.08333333   3                          459800
   857864  106.33333333   2                          459800
```

Would result in

```
orders_id  order_total    products_quantity  customers_id  
---------  -------------  -----------------  --------------
  1140867  99.95833333    1                          459800
   860100  125.08333333   3                          459800
```

I've attempted to write a cursor to iterate over each result, storing the last order_total and checking the current row for a diff.

This works as long as the negative order comes before or after the positive. Unfortunately, this wont always be the case.

Can anyone explain what approach/methods I should adhere to ensure the output below is achieved?

Comment: Your problem is overly simplified.  What would happen if the first or second row were duplicated again?  Which version would you keep?

Comment: If they were duplicated then one would be brought through and the second would cancel the the next one out. Why we haven't an easy way to relate two orders is beyond me... This is proving a PITA to calculate

Comment: "then the second" implies a significance in ordering you've not told us about. This is either impossible or a very *very* poor problems statement.

Comment: thanks @symcbean The ordering is irrelevant. If one order nets out another by that customers ID, then neither should be included. If it doesn't and quantity is > 0 I will assume this to be another order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the problem is impossible. Consider:

```
orders_id  order_total    customers_id  
---------  -------------  --------------
1          -100           1
2          50             1
3          50             1
4          50             1
```

(I assume that you only want to consider that each value only affects the "net" for a specific customer)

In the case above, orders_id=1 might be considered to offset 2 and 3 leaving 4 in the output, 3 4 leaving 2 in the output, or 2 and 4 leaving 3 in the output.

What if the lines with negative amounts are not an exact amount match for one or more of those with positives? Even if *some* combination of the negatives adds up to some combination of the positives, you would need to try every possible combination - just calculating the order of that algorithm makes my head hurt (O(N!)^2 I think).

Comment: I think the assumption here is that order cancellation is EXACTLY the same as the order being cancelled, just the value is negative. In that case you could not tell which one of the matching orders is cancelled, but you don't need this information anyway.

Comment: Thanks symcbean. The end goal is to calculate the orders a customer has made in a set date range. Unfortunately, refunds + exchanges are stored in the DB as normal orders with negative quantities. In short if it doesn't net out with another row, and the quantity is > 0 it needs to be included.

Comment: That only helps a little. The amounts must match and there is an implicit ordering (presumably a refund cannot be made before an order is processed). You've still not got a definitive relationship between a refund and the order it is a refund for. Problem is still unsolveable.

Comment: thanks for your help. you are correct. I managed to find a relation in the data that allowed me to exclude results based off other factors. Oh to poor design!